# Expand element 'up' instead of 'down'

Tags: html, css, reactjs

This is on the latest Chrome. If an element on a web page expands or contracts it does in a downward direction and pushes elements below it down. The only exception is if the page is scrolled to the bottom and the element contracts in which case the elements at the top of the viewport move down.

I would like to define an element such that if it changes height it does so in an upward direction and any elements below it don't move.

This is not an element that is in a fixed position. It is in the normal flow and could be anywhere on the screen at the time it resizes.

The use case is a form that affects the element above and I do not want the form bouncing around as it is filled in.

Some really simple code -

HTML:

```
<div class="topdiv">
  Top
</div>
<div class="bottomdiv">
  Bottom
</div>
```

and accompanying CSS:

```
.topdiv {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}

.topdiv:hover {
  height: 300px;
}

.bottomdiv {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: green;
}

.bottomdiv:hover {
  height: 300px;
}
```

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/vbrdsj06/1/

Hover over the top div and it expands pushing the bottom div down. I would like the bottom div to stay put and the top div to expand upwards beyond the top of the viewport.

Is this doable? A react solution would be acceptable.

Comment: What is making it expand and contract?

Comment: It'd be great if you could provide a snippet or a jsfiddle so we can test.

Comment: @epascarello. As elements are selected in the from below a list is updated in the div above. But as this list expands it pushes the form down a bit so the checkbox that you were just about to click has now moved. If i can make the div expand upwards the form would stay put.

Comment: Okay so you either need to make the list a constant size or you need to figure out how much the size changed and adjust the scroll position. There is no magic html/css for this

Answer (score 0):

You can "pull up" the page manually by setting the `margin-top` property to the body tag to the negative of the difference in the heights of the element before and after hovering it.

```js
$('.topdiv').hover(function() {
  document.body.style.marginTop = "-200px";
}, function() {
  document.body.style.marginTop = 0;
})
```

```css
.topdiv { width: 400px; height: 100px; margin: 10px; background-color: red; }
.topdiv:hover { height: 300px; }
.bottomdiv { width: 400px; height: 100px; margin: 10px; background-color: green; }
.bottomdiv:hover { height: 300px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="topdiv">
  Top
</div>
<div class="bottomdiv">
  Bottom
</div>
```

In ReactJS, you'd set a `mouseenter` and a `mouseleave` event with the functions I used above, I used jQuery here for simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `margin-top` of the first element.

```css
.topdiv {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}

.topdiv:hover {
  height: 300px;
  margin-top: -198px;
}

.bottomdiv {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: green;
}

.bottomdiv:hover {
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="topdiv">
  Top
</div>
<div class="bottomdiv">
  Bottom
</div>
```